# Converting a list of list of elements linto a two dimensional array

Tags: python

I am working on a project, but I am stuck on converting a list of notes (music notes) into a two dimensional array where the column labels is the time frame (cut) and the row labels are the pitch.

**Current**:

```py
pitchList = []
for i in range(len(soundDict)):
    HUNDlist = [] 
    for k in range(0,100):
        HUNDlist.append(False)
        
    pitchList.append(HUNDlist)
def logger(text):
    with open ("log3.txt","a") as logfi: logfi.write(str(text)+"\n")

for i in pitchList:
    
    for j in i:
        llldx = 0
        for item in finishibleSONG:
            for note in item:
                
                pitchList[j][MidiStringToInt(f"{note[0]}-{note[1]}")] = True
                print("CHECK", llldx, MidiStringToInt(f"{note[0]}-{note[1]}"))
            llldx += 1
        print("ITER COMPL")
df = pandas.DataFrame(pitchList)

df.to_csv("theCSV.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

**EXPECTED (in pitch list)**:

```py
[                            \/ turns on here
  [False, False, False, ... True, True, False,... False]. #This is pitch 60 for instance. It turns on there.
  [False, False, False, ... False, True, False,... False]
  ...
]
```

**finishibleSONG**
An array that is temporary.

```py
[[],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [('B', 3)],
 [('G', 1), ('B', 3)],
 [('B', 3)],
 [('G', 1), ('B', 3)],
 [('B', 3)],
 [('G', 1), ('B', 3)],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [],
 [('G', 1)],
 [('B', 3)],
 [('G', 1)]]
```

**Midi String to Int**
Converts a midi string to a midi pitch number

```py
def MidiStringToInt(midstr):
    Notes = [["C"],["C#","Db"],["D"],["D#","Eb"],["E"],["F"],["F#","Gb"],["G"],["G#","Ab"],["A"],["A#","Bb"],["B"]]
    answer = 0
    i = 0
    #Note
    letter = midstr.split('-')[0].upper()
    for note in Notes:
        for form in note:
            if letter.upper() == form:
                answer = i
                break;
        i += 1
    #Octave
    answer += (int(midstr[-1]))*12
    return answer
```

Comment: (a) this is not a minimum reproducible example, we're missing the definitions of some of the functions, like `MidiStringToInt`; (b) have you tried the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: As a side-note, rather than defining a `logger` function, why not use the standard library `logging` module?

Comment: `soundDict` is also missing. Would you please include it?